# Java Triangular kind of histogram

Tags: java, histogram

I need a bit of help with a project, I want to create a java program that creates a kind of histogram in the shape of triangles, its hard to explain so look at the following example

```
input : 3 1 12 0 7
output:

                           _
                          /|\
                         / | \
                        /  |  \
                       /   |   \
                      /    |    \                   _
                     /     |     \                 /|\
                    /      |      \               / | \
                   /       |       \             /  |  \
    _             /        |        \           /   |   \
   /|\           /         |         \         /    |    \
  / | \    _    /          |          \       /     |     \
 /  |  \  /|\  /           |           \  _  /      |      \
<=======><===><=========================><=><===============>
 |     |  | |  |                       |  |  |             |
```

in my code I've managed to create the input part, and the generator of the base, but the triangles/piramides generator doesnt make the correct spaces, anyone can help me?
here is my code to make the triangles (assuming the input is what is in the array *numbers* and *numbers2*):

```
public class Spires{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] numbers = {3,1,12,0,7};
    int counter = 6, max = 12;
    int[] numbers2 = {3,1,12,0,7};

        for(int row = max+1; row >= 0; --row) {
            System.out.println();
            for(int col = 0; col < counter-1; ++col) {
                if(numbers2[col] >= row){
                        for(int spacesleft = 1; spacesleft < (numbers2[col] + col)+row-1; ++spacesleft){
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    if(numbers2[col] != row){
                        System.out.print("/");
                        for(int c3 = 0; c3 < numbers2[col]-row-1; ++c3) {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.print("|");
                        for(int c3 = 0; c3 < numbers2[col]-row-1; ++c3) {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.print("\\");

                    }else{
                        System.out.print("_");
                    }
                    // for(int spacesright = 1; spacesright <  numbers2[col] + col + row -1; ++spacesright){
                        // System.out.print(" ");
                    // }                    
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
                        //base generator
        for(int i = 0; i<counter-1; ++i) {
            System.out.print("<");
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 2*numbers[i]+1; ++i2)  {
                System.out.print("=");
            }
            System.out.print(">");
        }       
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i<counter-1; ++i) {
            if(numbers[i] != 0){
                System.out.print(" |");
                for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 2*numbers[i]-1; ++i2)  {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("| ");
            }else{
                System.out.print(" | ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My output comes out like this:

```
                        _
                       /|\
                      / | \
                     /  |  \
                    /   |   \
                   /    |    \                _
                  /     |     \               /|\
                 /      |      \              / | \
                /       |       \             /  |  \
    _               /        |        \            /   |   \
   /|\              /         |         \           /    |    \
  / | \ _             /          |          \          /     |     \
 /  |  \/|\            /           |           \ _         /      |      \
<=======><===><=========================><=><===============>
 |     |  | |  |                       |  |  |             |
```

I need some help figuring out how to add the missing spaces and remove some

Comment: I'd use a StringBuilder and a List of Strings to build the histogram from the bottom up.  After creating the histogram, I'd print the List in reverse order.  My suggestion to you is to break up your monolithic code into methods.  Create a method for the base, the last line, and the triangle lines.  Since you said your problem was spacing the triangle lines, you'd have a lot less code to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

The reason that I'm providing this answer is to write about how to reason through a coding problem.  The triangle histogram was interesting enough for me to work out a solution.

Here's one test run:

```
Enter the heights of the triangles: 3 1 12 0 7

                           -                                 
                          /|\                                
                         / | \                               
                        /  |  \                              
                       /   |   \                             
                      /    |    \                   -        
                     /     |     \                 /|\       
                    /      |      \               / | \      
                   /       |       \             /  |  \     
    -             /        |        \           /   |   \    
   /|\           /         |         \         /    |    \   
  / | \    -    /          |          \       /     |     \  
 /  |  \  /|\  /           |           \  -  /      |      \ 
<=======><===><=========================><=><===============>
 |     |  | |  |                       |  |  |             | 

Enter the heights of the triangles:
```

### Reasoning

The heights of the triangles are input, and the histogram triangles are output.  Pressing the Enter key without typing any numbers lets the program know to exit.

When I looked at the histogram, I noticed 3 things.

1. I could create a Java class to form the triangle, and create an instance of the class for each triangle I needed to draw.  In the example test run, I create 5 triangles, so I create 5 instances of the class.
2. If I create the base row first, I can use positioning of the < and > signs to calculate where to start the triangle sides.
3. The histogram is much easier to create from the bottom up than from the top down.

Now, it helps a lot that I know I can use a StringBuilder to create a blank string and place characters within the blank string using the setCharAt method.  This way, I don't have to calculate the number of blanks in between and in the middle of the triangles.

It also helps a lot that I know I can use a List to store the output strings, and print them in the reverse order of their creation.

So, here' the first hint I can give you for solving coding problems.

> If something seems real hard to accomplish, ask someone if there's an easier way.

There may not be an easier way.  Some coding problems are that hard.  But sometimes, you may not be aware of an easier solution.

So, here's the code that produces the histogram.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleHistogram implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TriangleHistogram().run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<TriangleModel> triangleHistogram = readInput(scanner);

        while (triangleHistogram.size() > 0) {
            String baseString = createBaseString(triangleHistogram);
            String bottomString = createBottomString(triangleHistogram,
                    baseString.length());

            List<String> histogramStrings = new ArrayList<>();
            histogramStrings.add(bottomString);
            histogramStrings.add(baseString);
            createTriangleStrings(triangleHistogram, histogramStrings);

            displayHistogram(histogramStrings);

            triangleHistogram = readInput(scanner);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

    private List<TriangleModel> readInput(Scanner scanner) {
        List<TriangleModel> triangleHistogram = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("Enter the heights of the triangles: ");
        String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();

        if (!inputLine.trim().isEmpty()) {
            String[] triangleSizes = inputLine.split("\\s");
            for (int i = 0; i < triangleSizes.length; i++) {
                TriangleModel triangleModel = new TriangleModel(
                        Integer.parseInt(triangleSizes[i]));
                triangleHistogram.add(triangleModel);
            }
        }

        return triangleHistogram;
    }

    private String createBaseString(List<TriangleModel> triangleHistogram) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (TriangleModel triangleModel : triangleHistogram) {
            triangleModel.setColumns(builder);
            triangleModel.createBase(builder);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String createBottomString(List<TriangleModel> triangleHistogram,
            int length) {
        StringBuilder builder = createStringBuilder(' ', length);

        for (TriangleModel triangleModel : triangleHistogram) {
            triangleModel.createBottom(builder);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private void createTriangleStrings(List<TriangleModel> triangleHistogram,
            List<String> histogramStrings) {
        String histogramString = "";

        do {
            String baseString = histogramStrings.get(1);
            StringBuilder builder = createStringBuilder(' ',
                    baseString.length());

            for (TriangleModel triangleModel : triangleHistogram) {
                triangleModel.createTriangle(builder);
            }

            histogramString = builder.toString();
            histogramStrings.add(histogramString);
        } while (!histogramString.trim().isEmpty());

    }

    private StringBuilder createStringBuilder(char c, int length) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            builder.append(c);
        }

        return builder;
    }

    private void displayHistogram(List<String> histogramStrings) {
        for (int i = histogramStrings.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String line = histogramStrings.get(i);
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public class TriangleModel {
        private final int height;

        private int leftColumn;
        private int centerColumn;
        private int rightColumn;

        public TriangleModel(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        public void setColumns(StringBuilder builder) {
            this.leftColumn = builder.length() + 1;
            this.centerColumn = leftColumn + height;
            this.rightColumn = centerColumn + height;
        }

        public void createBase(StringBuilder builder) {
            builder.append('<');
            for (int i = 0; i < getBaseWidth(); i++) {
                builder.append('=');
            }
            builder.append('>');
        }

        public void createBottom(StringBuilder builder) {
            builder.setCharAt(leftColumn, '|');
            builder.setCharAt(rightColumn, '|');
        }

        public void createTriangle(StringBuilder builder) {
            if (leftColumn < rightColumn) {
                builder.setCharAt(leftColumn, '/');
                builder.setCharAt(centerColumn, '|');
                builder.setCharAt(rightColumn, '\\');

                leftColumn++;
                rightColumn--;
            } else if (leftColumn == rightColumn) {
                builder.setCharAt(centerColumn, '-');

                leftColumn++;
                rightColumn--;
            }
        }

        private int getBaseWidth() {
            return height + height + 1;
        }

    }

}
```

### Explanation

I made the main TringleHistogram class implement Runnable so that I could put the main code in the run method.  I don't like to put a lot of code in the constructor of the class.

The run method is a synopsis of what happens in the code.  I get the heights from the user, and I create the histogram.  I create the base line first, then the bottom line, then the triangles in reverse order.

The while loop in the run method uses a priming read.  I call the readInput method once before the while loop and once again at the end of the while loop.  That way, I don't have to skip any part of the while loop when the user just presses the Enter key.

The readInput method doesn't do any error checking.  Error checking could be added in the readInput method.

I broke up the code in the TriangleHistogram class into multiple methods.  Each method does what the name of the method says it does.  Naming methods is important to do descriptively.  Generally, I use a verb - noun construction.

The TriangleModel class draws a triangle.  Looking in the class, there's not much math involved.  As I create the base line, I set the columns of the left center, and right parts of the triangle.  As I create each line of the histogram, I adjust the left and right columns until they meet at the top of the triangle.

You can see in the TriangleModel methods that placing characters on a blank StringBuilder is much simpler than appending blanks and characters.

### Development

I didn't write the entire program in one shot.  I wrote small pieces of the program and tested them.  The advantage to writing a little and testing a little is that when you find a problem, you have a good idea where in the code the problem lies.

1. I wrote the readInput method and enough of the run method to exercise the while loop.  I wrote just enough of the TriangleModel class to hold the height.  The program didn't do anything but process the input, create a List of TriangleModel objects, and not crash.  The not crashing part was the most important.
2. I added the rest of the fields to the TriangleModel class and created the base line of the histogram.  Finally, some output I could look at! Yay!
3. I created the bottom line of the histogram.  This allowed me to veriy that the left column and right column of the triangle were defined correctly.
4. I created one line above the base of the histogram.  This allowed me to verify the center column of the triangle was defined correctly and the List of output strings was created and printed in reverse order.
5. I wrote the rest of the code.  This is where my program crashed first.  I forgot to adjust the left and right columns when they were equal.  I found the problem quickly because I knew the problem was in the new code.

Then I was done.  I spent some time cleaning up some of the code and making field names and method names more descriptive.

You can learn these techniques for writing code.  Here's the last hint I can give you.

> You're not writing code for a compiler.  You're writing code so that other people, including yourself 3 months later, can read and easily understand the code.

Start with broad ideas, and dive into more and more detail as you move further down the code.

I hope this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there!  Just a couple tweaks that need to be made.

1. The calculation for number of outside spaces on the left and right side of the triangle legs is actually very simple: `row + 1`.  Because each triangle is being built from the bottom up, triangles shown on row 0 (bottom row) need 1 space, row 1 need 2 spaces, etc.
2. If the current `row` is "above" the triangle column you are displaying, you still need to output spaces to mark a placeholder for that triangle.  So the `if (numbers2[col] >= row)` needs a corresponding `else` to display spaces instead.

Applying these two changes gets something like:

```
 if(numbers2[col] >= row){

    //            corrected calculation \-------/
    for(int spacesleft = 0; spacesleft < row + 1; ++spacesleft){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

     if(numbers2[col] != row){
         System.out.print("/");
         for(int c3 = 0; c3 < numbers2[col] - row - 1; ++c3) {
             System.out.print(" ");
         }
         System.out.print("|");
         for(int c3 = 0; c3 < numbers2[col] - row - 1; ++c3) {
             System.out.print(" ");
         }
         System.out.print("\\");

     }else{
         System.out.print("_");
     }

     //              corrected calculation \-------/
     for(int spacesright = 0; spacesright < row + 1; ++spacesright){
         System.out.print(" ");
     }

 // output spaces to fill area for that column and shift everything over properly
 } else {
    for (int spaces = 0; spaces < numbers2[col] * 2 + 3; spaces++)
        System.out.print(" ");
 }
```

This should output the histogram as expected.

---

Now I'd like you to consider why this code is challenging to work with.  There is a direct relationship to the number of variables and ideas you have to hold in your head at once, to the difficulty of reading and understanding a piece of code.

One way you could make this code easier to reason about is by breaking it up into different functions that handle different aspects of the problem individually.  For example, we might add methods for:

1. printing a certain number of spaces
2. printing one row of a triangle

Also it helps to use more variables with intuitive names, so you don't have to keep reasoning through the entire calculations. Here is an example that should demonstrate:

```
// output 'count' spaces
public static void printSpaces(int count) {
    for (int spaces = 0; spaces < count; spaces++) System.out.print(" ");
}

// output one row of a triangle based on supplied height
// and current display row, starting at 0=top row.
public static void printTriangleSection(int triangleHeight, int rowOfTriangle) {

    int triangleWidth = triangleHeight * 2 + 3; // total width taken up by this triangle
    int halfWidth = triangleHeight + 1;     // total width taken up by one side (excluding the middle)

    int spacesOutside = halfWidth - rowOfTriangle;  // total spaces outside of triangle hypotenuse
    int spacesInside = rowOfTriangle - 1;           // total spaces inside triangle hypotenuse

    if (rowOfTriangle < 0) {        // above the first row of the triangle
        printSpaces(triangleWidth);
    } else if (rowOfTriangle == 0) {
        printSpaces(spacesOutside);
        System.out.print("_");
        printSpaces(spacesOutside);
    } else {
        printSpaces(spacesOutside);
        System.out.print("/");
        printSpaces(spacesInside);
        System.out.print("|");
        printSpaces(spacesInside);
        System.out.print("\\");
        printSpaces(spacesOutside);
    }
}
```

Then the relevant part of your `main` method would simplify to this:

```
for(int row = max+1; row >= 0; --row) {
   System.out.println();
   for(int col = 0; col < counter-1; ++col) {
       printTriangleSection(numbers2[col], numbers2[col] - row);
   }
}
```